# PHP Form based on button clicked, submit value of Subscribe or Unsubscribe

Tags: php, html, forms, magento

I have a form with a Subscribe button and an Unsubscribe button. I want to, based on which button is clicked, submit the value of either Subscribe or Unsubscribe.

I've already put together what should happen based on if Subscribe or Unsubscribe is clicked. Now I just have to determine which Button is clicked.

Here is my HTML:

```
<form action="../external/multisubscribe.php" method="post" width="600px" style="margin: 0 auto;">
    <table style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle; width: 100%;">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle; width:25%; padding: 0 20px 0 20px;">
                    <a href="www.example.com">
                        <img style="width: 100%; margin: 0 auto;" src="{{media url='wysiwyg/spslogo.png'}}" alt="Pilot Shop" />
                    </a>
                </td>
                <td style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle; width:25%; padding: 0 20px 0 20px;">
                    <a href="http://example.com">
                        <img style="width: 60%; margin: 0 auto;" src="{{media url='wysiwyg/Aflogo.jpg'}}" alt="Journal" />
                    </a>
                </td>
                <td style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle; width:25%; padding: 0 20px 0 20px;">
                    <a href="http://example.com/">
                        <img style="width: 60%; margin: 0 auto;" alt="iPad Pilot News" src="//examplenetwork.com/ipad/files/2016/03/iPad-Pilot-News-header-544-white-300x99.png" />
                    </a>
                </td>
                <td style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle; width:25%; padding: padding: 0 20px 0 20px;">
                    <a href="http://example.com/">
                        <img style="width: 50%; margin: 0 auto;" alt="Student Pilot News" src="http://www.example.com/media/wysiwyg/Student-Pilot-News-final-140.png" />
                    </a>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle; width:25%; padding: 0 20px 0 20px;">
                    <p>The online magazine where readers are pilot in command. Opinion, analysis, tips and debate.</p>
                </td>
                <td style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle; width:25%; padding: 0 20px 0 20px;">
                    <p>The online magazine where readers are pilot in command. Opinion, analysis, tips and debate.</p>
                </td>
                <td style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle; width:25%; padding: 0 20px 0 20px;">
                    <p>Your #1 source for tips, tricks, videos and quizzes about flying with the iPad.</p>
                </td>
                <td style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle; width:25%; padding: 0 20px 0 20px;">
                    <p>Everything new pilots need, from free videos to a flight school directory.</p>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle; width:25%;">
                    <label>
                        <input style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle; margin: 0 auto; display: inline-block;" name="pilotshop" type="checkbox" /> Sign Me Up 
                    </label>
                </td>
                <td style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle; width:25%;">
                    <label>
                        <input style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle; margin: 0 auto; display: inline-block;" name="airfacts" type="checkbox" /> Sign Me Up 
                    </label>
                </td>
                <td style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle; width:25%;">
                    <label>
                        <input style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle; margin: 0 auto; display: inline-block;" name="ipad" type="checkbox" /> Sign Me Up 
                    </label>
                </td>
                <td style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle; width:25%;">
                    <label>
                        <input style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle; margin: 0 auto; display: inline-block;" name="learntofly" type="checkbox" /> Sign Me Up 
                    </label>
                </td>
            </tr>           
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <div style="text-align:center;vertical-align:center;width:100%;margin-top:3.0em;">
        <input style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle; margin: 0 auto;" name="email" placeholder="Enter Your Email" type="email" />
        <button style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle; margin: 0 auto;margin-top:1.200em;" type="submit" name="submit" title="Subscribe" class="button">Subscribe</button>
        <button style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle; margin: 0 auto;display: block; margin-top:2.500em;" type="submit" name="submit" title="Unsubscribe">Unsubscribe</button>
    </div>
    <input name="redirect" value="{{store url="email-subscribe-success"}}" type="hidden" />
    <input name="action" value="subscribe" type="hidden" />
</form>
```

This is my PHP, in multisubscribe.php, that the form action posts to.

```
<?php
include_once "../app/Mage.php";
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $choices = array();
    if (isset($_POST['airfacts'])) {
        $choices[] = 'airfacts';
    }
    if (isset($_POST['ipad'])) {
        $choices[] = 'ipad';
    }
    if (isset($_POST['learntofly'])) {
        $choices[] = 'learntofly';
    }
    if (isset($_POST['pilotshop'])) {
        $choices[] = 'pilotshop';
    }
    if (count($choices) == 0) {
        echo "Please choose at least one subscription.";
    } else {
        $email = $_POST['email']; //obtain email from post, place into $email variable
        $email = filter_var($email, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL); //sanitizing email
        wpSubscription($choices, $email, $_POST['action']);
    }
    $redirect = $_POST['redirect'];
    header('Location: ' . $redirect);
}

function wpSubscription($sites, $email, $action)
{
    $mh                    = curl_multi_init();
    $curl_reference_array  = array();
    $unsubscribe_url_array = array();

    foreach ($sites as $site) {

        if ($site == 'pilotshop' && $action =='subscribe') { //if $site is pilotshop, then perform soap xml integration with listrak
            $sh_param   = array( //setting username & password array
                'UserName' => "", //removed username & pass for stackoverflow
                'Password' => ""  //removed username & pass for stackoverflow
            );
            $authvalues = new SoapVar($sh_param, SOAP_ENC_OBJECT); //encoding username and password array
            $headers[]  = new SoapHeader("http://webservices.listrak.com/v31/", 'WSUser', $sh_param);
            $soapClient = new SoapClient("https://webservices.listrak.com/v31/IntegrationService.asmx?WSDL", array(
                'trace' => 1,
                'exceptions' => true,
                'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE,
                'soap_version' => SOAP_1_2
            ));

            $soapClient->__setSoapHeaders($headers);
            $params = array( //parameters for soap xml integration with listrak
                'WSContact' => array(
                    'EmailAddress' => $email,
                    'ListID' => '' //removed for stackoverflow
                ),
                'ProfileUpdateType' => 'Overwrite',
                'ExternalEventIDs' => '', //removed for stackoverflow
                'OverrideUnsubscribe' => true
            );

            try {

                $rest = $soapClient->SetContact($params); //using SetContact method, send parameters

            }
            catch (SoapFault $e) { //if an error occurs, display it

                echo '<pre>';

                print($e->getMessage());

                echo '</pre>';
            }
        } elseif ($site == 'airfacts') {
            $url = "http://example.com/" . $site . "/?na=ajaxsub";
        } elseif ($site == 'ipad') {
            $url = "http://example.com/" . $site . "/?na=ajaxsub";
        } elseif ($site == 'learntofly') {
            $url = "http://example.com/" . $site . "/?na=ajaxsub";
        } elseif ($action == 'unsubscribe') {
            $url = "http://example.com/unsubscribe.php";
        } else {
            return;
        }

        $fields = array(
            'ne' => $email,
            'site' => $site
        );
        $ch     = curl_init($url);
        if ($action == 'unsubscribe') {
            $returntransfer = true;
        } else {
            $returntransfer = false;
        }
        $opts = array(
            CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $fields,
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => $returntransfer
        );
        curl_setopt_array($ch, $opts);
        curl_multi_add_handle($mh, $ch);
        $curl_reference_array[] = $ch;
    }

    $active = null;

    do {
        $mrc = curl_multi_exec($mh, $active);
    } while ($active > 0);

    foreach ($curl_reference_array as $chref) {
        $html   = curl_multi_getcontent($chref);
        $chu    = curl_init($html);
        $fields = array(
            'ts' => time()
        );
        $opts   = array(
            CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $fields
        );
        curl_setopt_array($chu, $opts);
        curl_exec($chu);
        curl_close($chu);
        curl_multi_remove_handle($mh, $chref);
    }

    curl_multi_close($mh);
    return;
}

?>
```

Comment: Are you able to write some javascript in this page or not? I'm thinking in a javascript based answer, but I need your answer first.

Comment: @Hackerman I definitely can, within <script></script> tags.

Comment: Nice, let me work on the answer...give me a couple of minutes

Comment: add attribute value to tag button `value="subscribe"` and in php check `if($_POST['submit'] == 'subscribe'){ /* subscribe button was pressed */ }'`

Answer (score 0):

I made a few changes in your html, like adding a `name` to your `form`(I'm deleting some inline `css` just for clarification purposes), like:

```
<form action="../external/multisubscribe.php" method="post" name="theForm">
```

Also in both `submit` inputs I added an `id` and changed both `names`, like:

```
<button type="submit" name="subscribe" id="subscribe" class="button">Subscribe</button>
<button type="submit" name="unsubscribe" id="unsubscribe"title="Unsubscribe">Unsubscribe
</button>
```

I also change the `hidden` input, adding an `id`, like:

```
<input name="action" id="action" value="subscribe" type="hidden" />
```

Now, with the `javascript` code(it could be improved, I know):

```
document.getElementById('subscribe').addEventListener('click',function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  document.getElementById('action').value = 'subscribe';
  document.theForm.submit();
})

document.getElementById('unsubscribe').addEventListener('click',function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  document.getElementById('action').value = 'unsubscribe';
  document.theForm.submit();
})
```

> This way we are storing our action(`subscribe` or `unsubscribe`) into the `hidden` input.

Then in your `php` code, just check for your `action` value:

```
 $theAction = $_POST['action'];
 if($theAction === "subscribe"){
   //subscribe code  
 }
 else{
   //unsubscribe code
 }
```